# move a VM from one vsphere client to another

Tags: vmware, esxi

I'm trying to move a virtual machine which is currently residing in a vsphere client (192.168.10.X) to another host with another client (192.168.10.Y).

I'm just exporting the VM as OVF template from the source to a storage box which is getting extracted very slow (6468 min remaining) & once the export is completed I need to import the same in the other client.

Is there an alternative step for this? Pls advice!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Plan B, you could try SCPing the folder and all the contents from one host to the other.

Comment: Hi Kyle. Not sure on that. So, SCping would copy only the contents right & if i need to make like a clone of the original VM in a different host, I would need to either migrate the VM or it's OVF right.

Comment: Btw, this is a linux VM.

Comment: Those files make up a VM, so if you copy them off to another ESXi system, you can then register the VM through the vmname.vmx file. No need to clone or export or etc.

Answer (score 0):

I see that both vsphere client are on the same network. Do you have a datastore which is present on both vsphere client ?